# Whats the best performing way to find a max Attribute in an XML File?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Should I load the file as `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`, use Xml-to-LINQ?
Or is an `XPath` Query the way to go?
This is in general how my XML looks (more entries though):

```
<books>
 <book Date="2015/09/09 12:13:58">
   ...
 <book Date="2014/04/28 22:13:58">
</books>
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? Do you have concrete performance criteria to meet? I would try the simplest possible approach first, and see whether that performs well enough. (For me, that would be LINQ to XML: `var maxDate = XDocument.Load("file.xml").Root.Elements("book").Max(x => (DateTime) x.Attribute("Date"));` - although those `Date` attributes aren't ISO-8601, which means you may need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead. (If you control the data format, you should fix that ASAP...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Stopwatch` class here.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Implementation to find max attribute here
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Then you will find out which implementation is the fastest.